# add slick slider in vue component for laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i am trying to add slick slider to my laravel project in vue component like below this  is my slider.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="home-slider">
        <slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions">
            <a href="http://placehold.it/320x120">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x120" alt="">
            </a>
            ...
            <a href="http://placehold.it/420x220">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/420x220" alt="">
            </a>
        </slick>
        <i @click="slideLeft()" class="icon icon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Slick from 'vue-slick'
    new Vue({
        components: { Slick },
        data() {
            return {
                slickOptions: {
                    //options can be used from the plugin documentation
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    infinite: true,
                    accessibility: true,
                    adaptiveHeight: false,
                    arrows: true,
                    dots: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    edgeFriction: 0.30,
                    swipe: true
                }
            }
        },
        // All slick methods can be used too, example here
        methods: {
            next() {
                this.$refs.slick.next()
            },
            prev() {
                this.$refs.slick.prev()
            },
            reInit() {
                // Helpful if you have to deal with v-for to update dynamic lists
                this.$refs.slick.reSlick()
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

and in my blade file i have some thing like below :

```
.
.
.
.
            <home-slider url="/api/home/newpost"></home-slider>
.
.
.
.
```

but nothing is showing up in my app btw when i run the command as below :

```
npm install --no-optional vue-slick
```

i get the message as below :

```
├── jquery@3.4.1  extraneous
├── vue-carousel@0.18.0 
└── vue-slick@1.1.15  extraneous
```

does it mean that the packages have been installed or not ??
and if you know any easier package to be used inside vue project in laravel you can suggest me . 
and i would be so happy if you guys can help me import this slick vue in my laravel project . thanks

---